# ¿Es posible realizar registros sobre una tabla a partir de los resultados de una consulta de la misma tabla en MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Desarrollo un sistema de inventario de los insumos de un hotel. El detalle está en que se deben realizar requisiciones de insumos, pero automático, es decir, generar la cantidad a solicitar de cada insumo a partir del promedio de las anteriores cantidades conforme al historial de solicitudes de la tabla que existe en la BD. Ya generé la sentencia u operación que hace eso: hacer un insert a partir de una consulta (lo descubrí hace poco). En lo que necesito ayuda es una idea para hacer que dichos resultados de la operación sean ingresados inmediatamente como nuevos registros de solicitud en la misma tabla de donde saqué los promedios.

La BD la estoy desarrollando con MySQL.

Tenía la idea de hacer como una copia de ese resultado en otra tabla, en donde tienen que coincidir las columnas de ambas tablas y luego hacerlo viceversa: de la copia a la tabla de solicitudes. Pero el conflicto que existe es con los ID de esa copia, porque no se pueden replicar en la tabla origen, ya que de ahí mismo estoy sacando esos registros. Además de que tiene más conflictos con los datos de las otras columnas. Eso utilizando la operación que mencioné anteriormente.

Igual intenté utilizando la misma operación pero haciéndolo para la misma tabla, o sea sin copia, sino haciendo el insert con la consulta incluida directamente en la misma tabla. Pero tampoco resultó, porque igual está el conflicto con las columnas. Y además no solo es un registro de un sólo insumo, son muchos más de tajo que deben ingresar. Igual tampoco me da chance de hacerlo sobre la misma tabla.

La estructura de la tabla de requisiciones es la siguiente:

```
tbl_requisiciones (ID_requisicion,ID_insumo,cant_solicitada,ID_unidadM,ID_personal,fecha_solicitud)
```

La operación que intento realizar es la siguiente, pero tiene que ser con todos los resultados de la sentencia y registrarse en la misma tabla:

```
SELECT ID_insumo, AVG(cant_solicitada) FROM tbl_requisiciones GROUP BY ID_insumo
```

Se supone va dentro de un insert. Pero no funciona.

Comment: Qué significa que no te funciona? Te da un error?

Comment: Sí, en pocas palabras, haciéndolo sobre la misma tabla me dice que estoy operando sobre la misma tabla y no es posible sobre la misma tabla.

Comment: Por favor agrégalo a tu pregunta. Haz click en [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que ID_requisicion es auto numerado podrías hacer algo así:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_requisiciones (ID_insumo,cant_solicitada,ID_unidadM,ID_personal,fecha_solicitud)
SELECT ID_insumo, AVG(cant_solicitada) ,ID_unidadM,ID_personal,fecha_solicitud FROM tbl_requisiciones GROUP BY ID_insumo;
```

Si no es auto numerado tendrías que calcularlo como el mayor + 1 más o menos algo así:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_requisiciones (ID_requisicion,ID_insumo,cant_solicitada,ID_unidadM,ID_personal,fecha_solicitud)
SELECT (select max(ID_requisicion) from tbl_requisiciones) + (@row := @row + 1) AS ID_requisicion
, ID_insumo, AVG(cant_solicitada), ID_unidadM, ID_personal, NOW() FROM tbl_requisiciones, (SELECT @row := 0) r GROUP BY ID_insumo;
```

Comment: La primera me convence. Ya que el ID_requisicion es autogenerado. Es la misma estructura de sentencia. La única diferencia con el mío es que no estaba teniendo en cuenta a todas las columnas. Por eso no funciona, en primer lugar. Pero es debido a que estoy empeñada en que solo necesito los promedios. Ya que la fecha de solicitud se tiene que actualizar a la fecha actual en la que se está realizando la nueva solicitud, que deben aplicarse a todos los insumos que se van a pedir. En segundo,  también el error decía que no se puede sobre la misma tabla. Voy a volver a intentar pero con tu solución

Comment: "Lo sospeché desde un principio"...era eso...no estaba teniendo en cuenta a todas las demás columnas. Nada más en el ID_requisicion marcaba error porque no lo puse teniendo en cuenta que es autoincrementable, así como en la estructura que proporcionaste. Pero lo solucioné sustituyendo esa columna por null, como en un values, y resultó genial. Ahora nada más me queda el asunto de hacer eso incluyendo la actualización de la fecha, porque me los registra con las fechas que ya tenían anteriormente. Te agradezco mucho la aportación de tu parte. El detalle ya quedó solucionado. ¡¡Saludos!!